# What mistake have I made when trying to evaluate the limit $\lim \limits _ {n \to \infty}n - \sqrt{n+a} \sqrt{n+b}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Suppose $a$ and $b$ are positive constants.

$$\lim \limits _ {n \to \infty}n - \sqrt{n+a} \sqrt{n+b} = ?$$

**What I did first:**
I rearranged $\sqrt{n+a} \sqrt{n+b} = n \sqrt{1+ \frac{a}{n}} \sqrt{1+ \frac{b}{n}}$ and so: $$\lim \limits _ {n \to \infty} n - n \sqrt{1+ \frac{a}{n}} \sqrt{1+ \frac{b}{n}} = 0$$
Because both $\frac{a}{n}$ and $\frac{b}{n}$ tend to $0$.

**What would give a correct answer:**
Plotting the function $$f(x) = x - \sqrt{x+a} \sqrt{x+b}$$
Clearly indicates that it has an asymptote in $- \frac{a+b}{2}$. This result can be obtained multiplying the numerator and the denominator by $n + \sqrt{n+a} \sqrt{n+b}$:
$$\lim \limits _ {n \to \infty}n - \sqrt{n+a} \sqrt{n+b} = $$
$$-\lim \limits _{n \to \infty} \frac {n(a+b)}{n + \sqrt{n+a} \sqrt{n+b}} - \lim \limits _{n \to \infty} \frac {ab}{n + \sqrt{n+a} \sqrt{n+b}}$$
The second limit is clearly $0$ and the first one gives the correct answer (dividing the numerator and denominator by $n$).

Why the first way I tried is wrong? I might have done something silly but I cannot find it.

Comment: Before calculating, *look*. For example if $a=b=17$ the function is identically $-17$, so the limit is $-17$.

Comment: André makes a good point that is useful often. If you're unsure of something, see if you can just spot a way to simplify it in a special case and see what happens. Setting $a = b$ will get ride of the square root. Also, you've realised that you've made a mistake in your limit so try applying your principle to something else.

Comment: Your principle claims that since both $n$ and $n-1$ tend to $\infty$ as $n$ tends to $\infty$, then
$$n - (n-1) = 1$$
tends to $\infty$ as $n$ tends to $\infty$. This is obviously wrong, so you know that you must have made some mistake in this stage. (You could have made another mistake before, but often it's just one error.) Little checks are often very helpful! :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your initial approach was fine.  Just use the expansion $\sqrt{1+\frac{a}{n}}=1+\frac{a}{2n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$ to show that

$$\begin{align}
\sqrt{1+\frac{a}{n}}\sqrt{1+\frac{b}{n}}&=\left(1+\frac{a}{2n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)\left(1+\frac{b}{2n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)\\\\\
&=1+\frac{a+b}{2n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)
\end{align}$$

Finally we have

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(n-\sqrt{n+a}\sqrt{n+b}\right)&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\,n\,\left( 1-1-\frac{a+b}{2n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)\\\\
&=-\frac{a+b}{2}\end{align}$$

Comment: Nice answer! Where can I learn more about $\sqrt{1+\frac{a}{n}}=1+\frac{a}{2n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$. It didn't occur to me right away.

Comment: Thank you!  The expansion is effectively based on the extended mean-value theorem, which is related to the Taylor series (or Taylor series with remainder).  Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks. It does. I have forgotten some of the numerical analysis stuff since I took it almost 3 years ago. I have to do a comprehensive exam next term in numerical analysis so hopefully I will learn more about it.

Comment: @TylerHilton Sincere best wishes on your comprehensive exam!  You'll do fine

Comment: @TylerHilton: You don't need anything as complicated as Taylor series or mean-value theorem. $1+x-\frac{1}{2}x^2 \le \sqrt{1+2x} \le 1+x$ for any $x \ge 0$ just by squaring all three (they are all positive) and comparing.

Comment: @TylerHilton: Simply squaring gives the right-hand inequality for $x \ge 0$ and also the left-hand inequalty for $x \in [0,4]$, since $(1+2x+x^2)-(x^2+x^3)+\frac{1}{4}x^4 \le 1+2x$. The left-hand inequality is trivial for $x > 4$ since $1+x-\frac{1}{2}x^2 < 1+x-2x < 0$. We do not need generalization unlike what Dr. MV says, since we immediately get $1+\frac{a}{2n}-\frac{a^2}{8n^2} \le \sqrt{1+\frac{a}{n}} \le 1+\frac{a}{2n}$ for any $a \ge 0$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}^+$.

Comment: @Dr.MV: Yes it's not that I don't like asymptotic expansions like Taylor series. I agree that they are the best general way, but they require much more analysis than necessary, all the way up to derivatives in order to get the result. I feel that simple methods should be grasped thoroughly first so that one gets a very good understanding of simple behaviour like that of polynomials and radicals, and then certainly one should move on to more powerful techniques for general functions, as you have mentioned. =)

Comment: I think your approach using taylor expansion was very nice, thank you

Comment: @ElCid Thank you!  And you're most welcome.  It was my pleasure.

Answer (score 8):

It is true that both $a/n$ and $b/n$ tend to $0$ and $n\to\infty$, however the factor of $n$ in that term is approaching $\infty$ at the same time. So, analyzing this way, the second term gives the form $\infty\cdot 1$ and so the entire expression gives the indeterminate form $\infty-\infty$.

Comment: The second term has the form $\infty\cdot 1$... The problem is, that the final form is $\infty-\infty$...

Comment: Yes. You are absolutely right.

Answer (score 5):

Another approach:

$$\sqrt{a+n}\sqrt{b+n}=\sqrt{ab+(a+b)n+n^2}$$ and

$$\begin{align}n-\sqrt{n+a}\sqrt{n+b}&=\frac{n^2-(n+a)(n+b)}{n+\sqrt{n^2+(a+b)n+ab}}\\
&=\frac{-(a+b)n-ab}{n+\sqrt{n^2+(a+b)n+ab}}\\
&=\frac{-(a+b)-\frac{ab}{n}}{1 + \sqrt{1+\frac{a+b}{n} + \frac{ab}{n^2}}}
\end{align}$$

The numerator converges to $-(a+b)$ and the denominator converges to $2$.

Answer (score 1):

You can only write $$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n-b_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n-\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n$$ when both $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n$ exist. Note, that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\infty$ means, that $(a_n)$ does not converges.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is in this equality:
\begin{equation*}
\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty }n-n\sqrt{1+\frac{a}{n}}\sqrt{1+\frac{b}{n}}%
=0\ \ \ \ \ \ (Here\ it\ is).
\end{equation*}
Explanation. You known that 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }n &=&+\infty ,\ \ \ and \\
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }n\sqrt{1+\frac{a}{n}}\sqrt{1+\frac{b}{n}}
&=&+\infty ,\ \ \ too.
\end{eqnarray*}
However, it seems that you forget that $\infty -\infty $ is an indetermined
form, that is, when one have
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }a_{n}=\infty ,\ \ \ \ \ and\ \ \ \ \ \
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }b_{n}=\infty 
\end{equation*}
then one cannot give any conclusion about
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }(a_{n}-b_{n})
\end{equation*}
because one can have many situations. In this case one should make some
further study. For this example you use the classic technique which consists
of multiplying and dividing by what is called the conjugate of the original
expression, as follows (step by step)
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left( n-n\sqrt{1+\frac{a}{n}}\sqrt{1+\frac{b}{n}}\right)  &=&\left( n-n%
\sqrt{1+\frac{a}{n}}\sqrt{1+\frac{b}{n}}\right) \left( \frac{n+n\sqrt{1+%
\frac{a}{n}}\sqrt{1+\frac{b}{n}}}{n+n\sqrt{1+\frac{a}{n}}\sqrt{1+\frac{b}{n}}%
}\right)  \\
&=&\frac{n^{2}-\left( n\sqrt{1+\frac{a}{n}}\sqrt{1+\frac{b}{n}}\right) ^{2}}{%
n+n\sqrt{1+\frac{a}{n}}\sqrt{1+\frac{b}{n}}},\ \ \ \ \ \
((x-y)(x+y)=x^{2}-y^{2}) \\
&=&\frac{n^{2}-n^{2}(1+\frac{a}{n})(1+\frac{b}{n})}{n+n\sqrt{1+\frac{a}{n}}%
\sqrt{1+\frac{b}{n}}} \\
&=&\frac{n^{2}(1-(1+\frac{a}{n})(1+\frac{b}{n}))}{n(1+\sqrt{1+\frac{a}{n}}%
\sqrt{1+\frac{b}{n}})} \\
&=&\frac{n(1-\left( 1+\frac{a}{n}+\frac{b}{n}+\frac{ab}{n^{2}}\right) )}{(1+%
\sqrt{1+\frac{a}{n}}\sqrt{1+\frac{b}{n}})} \\
&=&\frac{-(a+b+\frac{ab}{n})}{(1+\sqrt{1+\frac{a}{n}}\sqrt{1+\frac{b}{n}})}
\end{eqnarray*}
therefore, passing to the limit one gets
\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\left( n-n\sqrt{1+\frac{a}{n}}\sqrt{1+\frac{b}{n}}%
\right)  &=&\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{-(a+b+\frac{ab}{n})}{(1+\sqrt{1+%
\frac{a}{n}}\sqrt{1+\frac{b}{n}})} \\
&=&\frac{-(a+b+0)}{1+\sqrt{1+0}\sqrt{1+0}}=-\frac{(a+b)}{2}
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 0):

one way to see this is to use the binomial theorem. here is how it goes:

$$(n + a)^{1/2} = n^{1/2} + \frac12n^{-1/2}a + \cdots\\
\sqrt{n+a}\sqrt{n+b} = \left(\sqrt n + \frac a{2\sqrt n}+\cdots\right) \left(\sqrt n + \frac b{2\sqrt n}+\cdots\right) = n + \frac12(a+b)+\cdots   $$

therefore $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(n - \sqrt{n+a}\sqrt{n+b}\right) =-\frac12(a+b). $$

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to solving this is via L'Hopital's rule. For this, we first need to do a bit of rearranging...

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1-\sqrt{1+a/n}\sqrt{1+b/n}}{1/n}
$$
which, letting $m=1/n$, gives us
$$
\lim_{m\to0} \frac{1-\sqrt{1+am}\sqrt{1+bm}}{m}
$$
It is from here that L'Hopital's rule (in this case, it's equivalent to evaluating the derivative of $1-\sqrt{1+ax}\sqrt{1+bx}$ at $x=0$) can be applied, namely
$$
\lim_{m\to0} \frac{-\frac12\left(\frac{a\sqrt{1+bm}}{\sqrt{1+am}}+\frac{b\sqrt{1+am}}{\sqrt{1+bm}}\right)}{1} = -\frac{a+b}2
$$